# Symfony 3.4 dynamic name and data

Tags: symfony-3.4

I changed symfony version to `3.4` and to face problem with form component
Before I use form like service, first created and modify and then create it. But now it changes, `create` function waiting class name. And I don't know how in this situation customization from. Example in symfony `3.3` I had loop where I create many form with specific name and data

```
foreach ($taskExecutions as $i => $execution) {

            $wtf = $this->getChoiceFiledType();
            $wtf->setDataChoice($workTypeObjects);
            $name = 'work_type_object';
            $wtf->setName("{$name}_id_{$i}");
            $wtf->setPlaceHolder($this->getAdditionalFunction()
                ->transLocal('select_default_value', 'common'));
            $renderValue['renderFormWT'] = $this->getFormFactoryInterface()
                ->create(
                    $wtf,
                    null,
                    ['attr' => ['class' => 'work_type_object_id', 'id' => "{$name}_form_{$i}"]]
                )
                ->createView();

 }
```

my form extend from custom parents

```
class ChoiceFiledType extends ExtendsTimeSheetsFilterForm
{
/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'required' => false,
        'choices' => $this->getDataChoice(),
        'empty_value' => $this->getPlaceHolder(),
    ]);
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType';
}
}
```

parent class with options:

```
class ExtendsTimeSheetsFilterForm extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $name = 'timesheets';

/**
 * @var array
 */
private $dataChoice = [];

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $placeHolder = '';

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @param string $name
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getDataChoice()
{
    return $this->dataChoice;
}

/**
 * @param array $dataChoice
 */
public function setDataChoice($dataChoice)
{
    $this->dataChoice = $dataChoice;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getPlaceHolder()
{
    return $this->placeHolder;
}

/**
 * @param string $placeHolder
 */
public function setPlaceHolder($placeHolder)
{
    $this->placeHolder = $placeHolder;
}
}
```

in new version symfony I don't have opportunity get form like service and then customize some data like this

```
            $wtf = $this->getChoiceFiledType();
            $wtf->setDataChoice($workTypeObjects);
            $name = 'work_type_object';
            $wtf->setName("{$name}_id_{$i}");
            $wtf->setPlaceHolder($this->getAdditionalFunction()
                ->transLocal('select_default_value', 'common'));
```

Only what I can this is create from use string class name, but... how to modify data before ? Example custom name form or I want to have opportunity change `dataChoice` or `placeholder`

```
                $renderValue['renderFormWT'] = $this->getFormFactoryInterface()
                ->create(
                    ChoiceFiledType::class,
                    null,
                    ['attr' => ['class' => 'work_type_object_id', 'id' => "{$name}_form_{$i}"]]
                )
                ->createView();
```

how it's works in symfony 3.4 or maybe another way for this ?

Answer (score 0):

As most of the time, answer is [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#using-aliases-to-enable-autowiring)...

My service definition :

```
app.security_handler:
  class: App\Listener\Security\SecurityHandler

App\Listener\Security\SecurityHandler: '@app.security_handler'
```

in `security.yaml` now :

```
form_login:
  login_path: /admin/login
  check_path: /admin/login
  default_target_path: /admin
  username_parameter: login[username_or_email]
  password_parameter: login[password]

  success_handler:    app.security_handler
  failure_handler:    app.security_handler
```

Comment: my answer about form name in DOM and dynamic data, like in example in question ...